# Check my pagination code.my values not sticking with form when paginating.but value are coming

Tags: php, pagination

```
<?php
$per_page=10;
if(isset($_GET['page'])) 
{
$page = $_GET['page'];
$start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page+1;
$per_page=$start_from+9;
}
else 
{
$page=1;
$start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;
}
$pincode=$_POST['pincode'];
$categorypincode=$_POST['categorypincode'];
$tutorname=$_POST['tutorname'];
$sql = "SELECT  tr.*, t.*  FROM  tinfo  t left join tutorregistration tr  on  tr. tid=t.tsid where pincode LIKE '%$pincode%'";
if($pincode!='' &&  $categorypincode!='' ){
$sql .= " and classconducted LIKE '%$categorypincode%'";
}
if($pincode!='' &&  $categorypincode!='' &&  $tutorname!=''){
$sql .= " and name LIKE '%$tutorname%'";
}
$sql.="LIMIT $start_from, $per_page";
//echo $sql;
$sql = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<form name="f1" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="pincode"     id="zipsearch"  value='<?php echo $pincode;?>'  class="buttonlengths" placeholder="Search By pincode,Area,State" required/><br/><br/>
<select name="categorypincode" ize="40" class="buttonlengths" />
<option value="">Sort By Subject</option>
<option value="Class I-V Tuition" <?php  if($categorypincode=='Class I-V Tuition') { echo 'selected'; }?>>Class I-V Tuition</option>
<option value="Class VI-VIII Tuition" <?php  if($categorypincode=='Class VI-VIII Tuition') { echo 'selected'; }?>>Class VI-VIII Tuition</option> <input type="text" name="tutorname" value="<?php echo $tutorname; ?>" class="buttonlengths" placeholder="Search By Tutor Name"/><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" id="tbx2"  name="submitpincode" value="Search"/>
</form>
<?php
$query = "SELECT  tr.*, t.*  FROM  tinfo  t left join tutorregistration tr  on  tr. tid=t.tsid";
$result = mysql_query($query);
// Count the total records
$total_records = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "showing".$start_from."to".$per_page."of".$total_records."<Br/>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$v=$row['tinfoid'];
?>
<?php  echo  '<a  href="#" id="downloadpdf"  ><span class="details" style="cursor:none";>Name:</span>'.$row['name'].'</a>';?><Br/><Br/>
<?php echo  '<span class="details">Years of Experience:</span>'.$row['texper'];?><Br/><Br/>
<?php
}
$total_records = mysql_num_rows($result);
$total_pages = ceil($total_records /10);
echo "<center><a href='itoriginal.php?page=1'>".'First Page'."</a> ";
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
echo "<a href='itoriginal.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
};
echo "<a href='itoriginal.php?page=$total_pages'>".'Last Page'."</a></center> ";
?>
```

I achieved the pagination like this I go the output like this first page: Showing 1 to 10 of 200 record,second page: It should show 11 to 20 of 200, I am happy with this, please cross check what I did, just I found my own idead,etc.Now When I paginate, Assume if i click page3 link the values are not sticking with the form fields.kindly cross check and tell me where to set condition in form field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify code as follow.

```
$page=1;
$per_page=10;
if(isset($_GET['page'])) 
{
      $page = $_GET['page'];
}

$start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;
```

Add space before LIMIT .

```
$sql.=" LIMIT $start_from, $per_page";
```

Set pagination url with the post data **pincode**

```
echo "<center><a href='itoriginal.php?page=1&pincode=$pincode&categorypincode=$categorypincode' >".'First Page'."</a> ";
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
echo "<a href='test.php?page=".$i."&pincode=$pincode&categorypincode=$categorypincode'>".$i."</a> ";
};
echo "<a href='itoriginal.php?page=$total_pages&pincode=$pincode&categorypincode=$categorypincode'>".'Last Page'."</a></center> ";
```

get pincode as follow,

```
$pincode=$_REQUEST['pincode'];
```

Comment: Thanks  KT, Is my logic is correct and when I pagination my values are not sticking.please do needful for me and it will useful for future user.The code I implemented this one is $per_page=10;
if(isset($_GET['page'])) 
{
$page = $_GET['page'];
$start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page+1;
$per_page=$start_from+9;
}
else 
{
$page=1;
$start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;
} working for me. here now problem is  paginating

Comment: @divyakodeeswaran  Did you print **$sql** and check ? was it correct . And print result of **mysql_query($sql);**

Comment: yes  It is working  fine now the problem is when I click page 4 the values are not sticking with form fields, I don't know how to set the condition in form fields,

Comment: @divyakodeeswaran Can you say which code is not working?

Comment: no, if I click page 3 the values are not sticking with form fields.generally if you see my form data pincode $pincode=$_POST['pincode'];
Now I am taking about this <input type="text" name="pincode"     id="zipsearch"  value='<?php echo $pincode;?>'  class="buttonlengths" placeholder="Search By pincode,Area,State" required/> here just I am echo $pincode, when page2 these goes out from form fields

Comment: @divyakodeeswaran Did you write all code within one .php file?

Comment: Thanks, Here data is showing in url. Now my question is .I want to retrieve the data using  $_get and pass to sql or what to do guide me , I am struggling  here where to put if condition in form

Comment: I have done like this in  value='<?php if($_GET['pincode'])echo $pincode; else echo $pincode;?>'  unable to get the values check please

Comment: @divyakodeeswaran `$pincode=$_REQUEST['pincode'];` Try this

Comment: $pincode=$_REQUEST['pincode'];
$categorypincode=$_REQUEST['categorypincode'];
$tutorname=$_REQUEST['tutorname'];   Yes I got the values in form for $pincode like wise for  $categorypincode is not coming check please. once thanks anything we need to change

Comment: In page2 In echo the $sql it shows SELECT tr.*, t.* FROM tinfo t left join tutorregistration tr on tr. tid=t.tsid where pincode LIKE '%coimbatore%' and classconducted LIKE '%Class I-V Tuition%'LIMIT 11, 20 but result is not coming, if i remove the limit 11, 20 data is coming check please

Comment: @divyakodeeswaran put a space before **LIMIT**

Comment: I have given space data not coming i tested in db, it shows  MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0028 sec )

Comment: @divyakodeeswaran Check your all constrains are correct or not. If they are correct check is there data match with constrains.

Comment: I have checked. I am unable to trigger out,limit is not matching with sql please check with once again from first we almost done. I am checking with phpmyadmin panel

Comment: @divyakodeeswaran If this is working for you, mark as correct